# How to make that an input have information in it

Tags: php, html, input

I am doing a (very basic) calculator in php and I want that the inputs with the numbers keep them. As far as i know there is any way to have an input with text inside already. Also, placeholder is **NOT** what i need because i want that the person, if he mistakes, could easily erase one or two numbers instead of re-writting everything. And (if possible) i would like to know if i can use php variables in it

Here is my code:

```
<html>
 <?php
 $numero1 = $_GET['numero1'];
 $numero2 = $_GET['numero2'];
 $calculo = $_GET['calculo'];
    if($numero1 == null){
        $numero1 = 0;
    }
    if($numero2 == null){
        $numero2 = 0;
    }
    ?>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Calculadora</title>
    <style>
        body{
            text-align: center;
        }
        h4{
            width: 50px;
        }
        
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Calculadora</h1>
    <form method="GET", action="calculadora.php">
       
        <input type="number" name="numero1" ><?php=$_GET['numero1'];?></input>
        <br>
        <br>
        <select name="calculo">
            <option value="suma">+</option>
            <option value="resta">-</option>
            <option value="multi">*</option>
            <option value="divi">/</option>
        </select>
        
         <br>
         <br>
        <input type="number" name="numero2"><?php=  $_GET['numero2'];?></input>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit", name="calcular", value="Calcular"></submit>
    </form>
    <p>=</p>
    <h2>
    <?php
    if($calculo == 'suma'){
        echo $numero1 + $numero2;
    }elseif($calculo == 'resta'){
        echo $numero1 - $numero2;
    }elseif($calculo == 'multi'){
        echo $numero1 * $numero2;
    }else{
        echo $numero1 / $numero2;
    }
    

?></h2>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [value attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#htmlattrdefvalue) for input fields will be the key here.

A quick example would be:

```
<input type="number" name="numero2" value="<?php echo $_GET['numero2']; ?>" />
```

Comment: i know that this is other thing but could you tell me is there is something as value for select? anyways, thank you very much!

Comment: @EzeTxle For select fields, you would want to use [selected attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option#attributes) on the option tag. It will make the given option as currently active / selected.